# Realtime Rails with Pusher event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, pusher

I am new to rails and javascript and I am having a tough time registering a jQuery function to an event. I have done it in another project, and I am almost copying this one line by line, yet it is still not working. Here is my code

First I added the pusher gem to my gemfile

```
gem 'pusher'
```

Then I ran bundle install

Then I added these lines to environment.rb

```
require 'pusher'

Pusher.app_id = **
Pusher.key = **
Pusher.secret = **
```

Then I added the pusher script to the head of my application.html

application.html.erb

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <!-- Uncomment to make IE8 render like IE7 -->
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" /> -->

    <!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Untitled" %></title>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/custom.modernizr" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "http://js.pusher.com/2.0/pusher.min.js" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
```

Next, I included the pusher.js file in application.js

```
//= require pusher
```

And finally, here is my pusher.js file

```
var pusher = new Pusher('MY KEY');

var myChannel = pusher.subscribe('job-channel');
$(document).ready(function() {

    myChannel.bind('job-added', function(data) {
        addJob(data)
    });

    function addJob(data) {
        var new_job = "<h1> TEST </h1>";
        $('.job_list').append(new_job)
    }

});
```

I activate the event in the controller like this

```
Pusher['job-channel'].trigger('job-added', @job.to_json)
```

And that doesnt work, but even when I used Pushers event creator, it also doesnt work.

I tried running the jQuery through the debugger and the $(document).ready and pusher stuff seems to work perfectly, but it just doesnt execute `addJob` when I activate the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this problem, I started a new app in pusher and I selected Enable Encryption and Enable Client Events. You have to start a new app, you cant just update to these settings in the Pusher App settings. This is bug pusher should fix!

Comment: [Client events](http://pusher.com/docs/client_events) are events triggered from the client and have a `client-` prefix. So, that won't be anything to do with the problem you experience. I also can't see how enabling encryption (forcing SSL WebSocket connections) would fix any problem that you are seeing because pusher-js handles failover to a secure connection if an unsecured one does not connect. I think it's highly likely that another change you made resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the job to the `pusher` object, not the `myChannel` object. Also, I have those objects being defined within my `document.ready` section, but I doubt that matters.

Comment: I got the idea from here http://pusher.com/docs/javascript_quick_start. They bind to the channel

Comment: Huh, it does look that way. But in my application which uses pusher I bind my events to my pusher object and it works great for me.

Comment: Yep - you should definitely bind to events on the channel object. There is a `bind` and `bind_all` on the `Pusher` object (see https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js/blob/v2.0.4/src/pusher.js#L123) but we don't encourage/publicise the use of those.